# How to deal with help-desk questions from pre-sale?

Tags: discussion, questions

A lot of people participated in the initial coin offering for Ethereum two years before it launched. Today, four years later, people check out their wallets and sometimes have issues with the [presale](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presale).

There used to be a help-desk operated by the foundation at `helpdesk@ethereum.com` but apparently this does not exist anymore. Instead, it auto-replies to use Ethereum Stack Exchange to ask questions. However, this yields threads like the following:

- [presale ether wallet gives 0 funds](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/87)
- [Bought Ether from ethereum presale (genesis) Forgot password](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/12273/87)

Without having access to pre-sale details for each user, it's very unlikely the community can assist with those issues. How to deal with help-desk questions from pre-sale participants?

Comment: So it would be just great in case you can help me with the thread https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/presale-ether-wallet-gives-0-funds

Answer (score 4):

The helpdesk email is no longer active at the foundation. It was not meant to stay open as long as it has. We are currently resolving the final few emails that have come in over the last 6 months. I was the last person to maintain helpdesk@ethereum.org before we closed it down. I will eventually get around to writing up some answers to people's questions regarding the pre-sale.